# want to make dropdown list for selecting by order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have marksheet project in which, subject controller - add, edit, delete subject., student controller - add student, map(make) result, check result(based on map-make result(privous method i wrote) data), now i want to add another page namely Subject Order which redirect on subject controller and in subject controller want to introduce new method, teacher can change subject order to give credit(value) so that method used for changing subject order, which can change subject order on database so student can see on result as per subject order by calling check result method. i know i have made it complicated but hope you will got my point as i am newbie to asp dot net core.

i want to expect teacher can change subject order by using dropdown box and it will change database row and it will effect subject order on result. thanks in advance.

Comment: What type database are you using?  You really want to perform an OrderBy with a custom sort method.  It probably better to do this in the database using RawSQL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide some code about this?